# How to assign column values to grid in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have 36 data points I want to assign to 6X6 grid as per the attached image.

Is there a way to tell Excel to take the point from the column to its location on the grid?

[image: picture]

Comment: What image? Your question is not clear.

Comment: You didn't attach anything. Also, when you repost this on SuperUser (which is the appropriate forum for this type of question), you should say where the data is coming from (i.e. is it already in the Excel sheet somewhere?).

Comment: Yes the data in excel. Simply, the question is how to transform the column data into grid (the empty table in the image) to be similar to the filled table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this standard formula in G3.

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$37, ABS(ISODD(ROW(1:1))*7-COLUMN(A:A))+(ROW(1:1)-1)*6)
```

Fill right and down.

[image: index_offset_snake]

Comment: I like how you approached the problem. But my data don't follow a pattern, so we can't use the the odd option. Think about those 36 numbers as random numbers such people as crime rates, and you want to put every data point into specific geographic location as per the image I attached.

Comment: The value(s) of the numbers does not matter beyond visually demonstrating the 'snaking' approach you chose to give the reorientation of the data.

Comment: @Jeepad, This is awesome. It worked for me and saved the day!